# JAVA RESTful server on Heroku: allow the upload/reading of the SQLite database

Tags: java, sqlite, rest, api, heroku

I'm developing a **RESTful web service**. I developed both the server and the client in JAVA using JPA and a **SQLite database**, and locally it works perfectly. I simply run the Application class of the client and it sends the requests to localhost and gets the responses in a perfect fashion.

However, when I deploy the server on [**Heroku**](https://www.heroku.com/), creating the .war needed (both using ant or exporting the .war from Eclipse), I successfully obtain the root element at myapp.example/rest/buildings, so it means that there is not any problems with the .war itself:

```
<buildings/>
```

However, if I try to do a simple POST request to add a new building (that locally works) I obtain the following 500 error:

```
**HTTP Status 500 - Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException**
```

I think the problem is that **it cannot know where to find the SQLite database**, so the question is:

**How can I upload the SQLite database to Heroku in order to allow my server to read the data from it and then to return responses to my local client?** It must be included in some way on the .war package? (I read that Heroku hasn't the support for this RDBMS, however I heard that there are workarounds, since the SQLite database is simply a file as many others).

Thank you in advance, and feel free to ask me other snippets or something else if the question is not clear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not want to use SQLite on Heroku because Heroku uses an [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). That means the changes to your sqlite database will be lost every 24 hours. The ephemeral filesystem is important because it ensures consistency on the server (i.e. prevents snowflake servers). SQLite also prevents your app from scaling up (i.e. running more instance of your app) because they would each have a different database.

Heroku provides free PostgreSQL instances, which I recommend you use. You'll need to change you JDBC driver and [configure your app use `JDBC_DATABASE_URL`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java#using-the-jdbc_database_url), but probably not much else.

*Sidenote: before you edited the post it looks like you mentioned a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` error. This is likely due to non-deterministic classpath loading.*

Comment: Thank you for your response! I correctly set up my database following the guide up to heroku run echo \$JDBC_DATABASE_URL. However, when I try to run queries on it using e.g. heroku pg:psql DATABASE_URL, the response is ---> Connecting to DATABASE_URL and it takes a very long time (it never finishes). How can I create my tables (or how can I import my sqlite database in it? Thank you very much indeed!

Comment: Did you try `heroku pg:psql` with no args?

Comment: Yes, and it didn't work (initially). However, I fixed the problem redoing the whole process. Thank you very much!